# How to load image from blob and show Image preview

Tags: reactjs, antd

I'm letting users upload a cover image.

I'm using ant design image upload. So it provides UI and the ability to crop images by default.

```
onst [fileList, setFileList] = useState([]);
          
          
    const onPreview = async (file) => {
    let src = file.url;
    if (!src) {
      src = await new Promise((resolve) => {
        const reader = new FileReader();
        reader.readAsDataURL(file.originFileObj);
        reader.onload = () => resolve(reader.result);
      });
    }
    const image = new Image();
    image.src = src;
    const imgWindow = window.open(src);
    imgWindow.document.write(image.outerHTML);
  };          


return (

<div>
          <UploadButton  
          fileList={fileList}
          beforeUpload={() => false}
          onChange={onChange}
          onPreview={onPreview} aspect={2} listType="picture" />

<div/>
)
```

Once the cropping is done, before reaching the server, I want to give users the ability to preview the imageso they can confirm it before upload.

On successfully, uploading the image, I accessed the thumb URL to show users. It's blurry and distorted.

So I went on check the network section and I found the blob as shown in Image, which gives me a quality image that I can show in the product.

I'm new to programming. I was wondering, how to access it.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can create a temporary image url out of a blob object.

```
const imageUrl = URL.createObjectURL(imageBlob) // imageBlob is of type blob
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I'm quite new to programming. Could you please help me identify which one is the imageBlob object here?

Comment: The imageBlob variable is the blob object which you were refering to in your question